# Google and Fb sign-in in same app

Tags: ios, facebook, integration, google-signin

I am trying to integrate both fb and new google sign in in a app but facing certain problems ,can some one help.

Actually in AppDelegate.m i have written this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSError* configureError;
    [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError: &configureError];
    NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);

    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;

    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {


    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application                                                         openURL:url                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication                                                       annotation:annotation] && [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                                     sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                            annotation:annotation];
}
```

And then I am creating the google login Button in another class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    fbLogingButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc]init];
    fbLogingButton.delegate = self;
    fbLogingButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:fbLogingButton];
    fbLogingButton.readPermissions =
    @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];

    googleSignInButton = [[GIDSignInButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 370,50, 150)];
    [self.view addSubview:googleSignInButton];


    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

But the app is crashing while launching in

```
[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError: &configureError];
```

and if I comment that its crashing if I click on Sign-In button

and the crash log says

> *2015-09-07 17:10:38.272 DemoAppSep[62471:3858047]*  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You
>   must specify |clientID| for |GIDSignIn|'
>    *First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001042fbc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000103f92bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00000001042fbb9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205     3   DemoAppSep 
>   0x00000001017581ef -[GIDSignIn assertValidParameters] + 77    4
>
>   DemoAppSep                          0x000000010175a589 -[GIDSignIn
>   signInWithOptions:] + 52  5   DemoAppSep
>
>   0x000000010175e5c6 -[GIDSignInButton pressed] + 331   6   UIKit
>
>   0x00000001046f6da2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] +*

Comment: error is showing  that you have not assigned clientID for google signin: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for FaceBook
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Use this for GooglePlus
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started

Must follow all steps

And in the end in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *) application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
BOOL wasHandled=false;;
if ([url.scheme hasPrefix:@"fb"]) {

      wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
    //Facebook callback
}
else       //Google Plus callback
{
  wasHandled=  [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];

}

NSLog ( @"application openURL");
NSLog ( @"URL = %@", url);
NSLog ( @"Application = %@", sourceApplication);

return wasHandled;
}
```

It will work.Thankyou